# Notepad++ and Python docstrings

Tags: python, notepad++, documentation

How do you bring up the Python document string (as a tool tip?) for a function or class when using Notepad++ as a code editor? Is this possible? I asked this question on Stack Overflow, and a user suggested it should just work, but it doesn't work for me. The files are .py files. Python is the primary language. I have NppExec installed.

Comment: Please, don't crosspost https://stackoverflow.com/q/55550026/372239

Comment: I can delete the other one - does this question belong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning on in Notepad++ the auto completion feature is done in the menu option of
*Settings > Preferences > Auto-Completion*.

You may also turn it off and use instead the manual
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
for your code, or 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
for language.

If the standard auto-completion is not enough, an alternative plugin is
available from
[3P : Progress Programmers Pal](http://jcaillon.github.io/3P/).